# ClickUp API in Node.js Promise.all() vs for loop with await

Tags: node.js, clickup-api

I want to delete all folders on ClickUp in bulk:

Here is the function that deletes a single folder:

```
async function deleteFolder(folderID) {
  try {
    await clickup.delete(`folder/${folderID}`);

    logger.log(
      "info",
      `DELETE folder: ${folderID} - Folder deleted successfully`
    );
  } catch (error) {
    logger.log(
      "error",
      `DELETE request to https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/folder/${folderID} failed. Error message: ${error.message}`
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the function that deletes all folders:

```
async function deleteAllFolders() {
  const teamID = await getWorkspaces();
  const spaceID = await getSpaces(teamID);
  const allFolders = await getFolders(spaceID);

  const promises = allFolders.folders.map(async (folder) =>
    deleteFolder(folder.id)
  );

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

This function uses the `Promise.all()`. When I call this function, only some of the folders are being deleted. Which folders get deleted seems to be random. I'm getting a 500 error for some of the folders.

Here is the error log I'm getting:

```
{"level":"error","message":"DELETE request to https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/folder/90110574307 failed. Response code: 500, response message: Request failed with status code 500","timestamp":"2023-10-08T18:35:39.431Z"}
```

However, when I use a for loop with `await`, everything works fine:

```
async function deleteAllFolders() {
  const teamID = await getWorkspaces();
  const spaceID = await getSpaces(teamID);
  const allFolders = await getFolders(spaceID);

  for (const folder of allFolders.folders) {
    await deleteFolder(folder.id);
  }
}
```

Why does the for loop work as expected, whereas the `Promise.all()` version doesn't? Does it have to do with rate limits, since `Promise.all()` does concurrent requests. The ClickUp API is limited to 100 requests per minute (in the free plan). But I'm only deleting 6 folders max.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ClickUp API has a rate limit of 100 requests per minute and then by using Promise.all() function you can make concurrent requests for all the folders.

This is my example code.

```
const deleteAllFolders = async () => {
  const teamID = await getWorkspaces();
  const spaceID = await getSpaces(teamID);
  const allFolders = await getFolders(spaceID);

  const promises = allFolders.folders.map(async (folder) => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 6000)); // Delay for 6 seconds    
    return deleteFolder(folder.id);
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```